# how to sample/group rows of dataframe to fix specific distributions within a group?

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, mathematical-optimization

I have a DataFrame `c` containing a columns `a`.

```
import numpy as np
a = np.random.randint(0,10, size=(100))
c = pd.DataFrame(a, columns=['a'])
```

I want to make random grouping of the rows of `c` such that there are 5 rows within each group and that there are 1 row in each group with `a < 3`

so for example:

```
[1,2,3,2,10]  <-- good group 
[1,1,3,4,6]  <-- good group
[2,4,7,3,7] <-- bad group
```

And if I ran out of rows to meet this criteria (for example I ran out of rows with `a < 1`) then ignore the rest of the dataframe

Currently I do this by creating a new column `group_id` and separate `c` by condition then iteratively sample from them until i ran out of candidates:

```
c['group_id'] = None
c_w_small_a = c[c.a < 3].copy()
c_w_large_a = c[c.a >= 3].copy()
group_id = 0
while len(c_w_small_a) >= 1 and len(c_w_large_a) >= 4:
   c.loc[c_w_small_a.sample(1, replace=False).index, 'group_id'] = group_id
   c.loc[c_w_large_a.sample(4, replace=False).index, 'group_id'] = group_id
   group_id += 1

c = c[c.group_id.apply(lambda x,x is not None)] # filter rows without id
c_groups = c.groupby('group_id')
```

The problem with this approach is that I can't generalize this approach with a more complex condition where the subsets overlap each other. such as

> at most 2 rows with `a > 2` and at least 1 rows with 'a == 3'.

I don't know how to code it in such way to maximize the number of groups I can get with this grouping. For example if a ==3 is very limited then I don't want a> 2 to choose 3 even though that satisfies it's condition.

Comment: `c = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(a,b)), columns=['a'])` what's `b`?

Comment: sorry initially had two columns but wasn't necessary in the toy example. However I can see how in some use case you might want to condition across multiple columns. For example in a dataset of people I want to group people in 5s such that at least 1 person is  between the age of 20-29 and they have a bachelor degree, where a is age and b is education level

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure, but I think that the problem you are describing is NP-complete and for this purpose I suggest that you think of a heuristic to find a satisfying solution. for this purpose you can write a greedy heuristic that will look like this :

```
def is_satisfying(group):
...     if (np.sum(group > 2) > 2) or (np.sum(group == 3) < 1): 
...             return False
...     else:
...             return True
```

and then to construct a group, you can write something like:

```
group = []
while len(group) != 4 : 
...     np.append(group, df['a'].sample(n=1))
...     if not is_satisfying(group):
...             group = group[:-1]
```

and in order to mark elements that have already been added to groups, you use some data structure that will enable you to filter the dataframe before sampling

Comment: hmm this was kind of the approach I was gearing towards just felt very inefficient using a while loop and just randomly sampling. Also I might be stuck in an infinite loop if i can't make the fourth group (but I guess i can use a counter to check how many times it ran). Thank's for the suggestion.